# Showing undefined when passing data using params in ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In my controller,

```
$scope.register = function(index) {
            $state.go('account.accountRegister', {obj: {accountType: $stateParams.accountType, accountName: $scope.data[index].accountName}})
        }
```

In  my router,

```
.state('account.accountRegister', {
                    url: '/register',
                    views: {
                        'mainView@':{
                            templateUrl: 'app/views/registration.html',
                            controller: 'registrationController',
                            params: {
                                obj: null
                            }
                        }
                    }

            })
```

In my registrationController iam getting data using

> $state.params.obj

But it is showing undefined. Help me if I did anything wrong here.
Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **`$stateParams`**

```
.controller('registrationController', function($scope, $stateParams) {
  $scope.paramOne = $stateParams.obj;
 }
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/CGJRog?p=preview)**

Comment: But, when I refresh the page the value gets replaced with the default value('defaultValueOne')

Comment: @SaiKumar yes it will, you need to use localstorage then

Comment: I came to know that, using localstorage is not correct solution here. So, please tell me another way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Get value as `$stateParams.obj` make sure to inject `$stateParams` in your controller.